# Not able to get an integer values from an SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple SQL query that is supposed to return numeric values which are needed for some later summation and they need to be integers. It looks like this:

```
$SumBod = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Bod FROM kandidati")
```

The problem is that the values aren't integers when i fetch them. 
I have tried using fetch_assoc(), mysqli_result, tried converting types like `$r=(int)$row['Bod']`   or `intval($row['Bod'])`
as I have found in solutions to similar questions here, but didn't make any difference for me.
I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't summarize those values that I need to get for a database with others which are given directly to that php script.

I really have searched for a solution but mostly everywhere I find those converting tips that I've tried.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if the columns in the table aren't integers. The results won't be either. Check your table and try again!

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, but you should have no problems when table is configured correctly

```
$SumBod = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CAST(Bod AS UNSIGNED) FROM kandidati")
```